# Resolution of camera feed

Tags: qt, opencv

I am developing an application that displays a feed from a digital microscope (connected to a laptop via USB port). My first approach was using OpenCV. The problem with that was that even if I set the resolution of the obtained frames to 1600x1200 (resolution supported by the camera), the resolution was 600x480 (or something along these lines). I then read some posts and learned that a library VideoInput http://muonics.net/school/spring05/videoInput/ is the one to use. The code below works well - I am able to save frames in the given resolution. The problem appears when I run the executable on another laptop. On HP the app saves the frames in the resolution of 1280x1024. I also tried a Toshiba laptop and the resolution was also 1280x1024. The camera came with a GUI from the developer and using that software the HP laptop saved images in the correct resolution of 1600x1200 but the Toshiba also lowered the resolution.

My question is - why would my app work well on my laptop yet would not work on either Toshiba or HP. Is there any way to fix it? The code below is for the VideoInput library that I am using. I would appreciate your help!

> VI.setIdealFramerate(device1, 15);
>       VI.setupDevice(device1, 1600, 1200, VI_COMPOSITE);

```
frame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(VI.getWidth(device1),VI.getHeight(device1)), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
```